# how can i query Java Caching System

Tags: java, caching, jcs

i'm use Java Caching System(JCS) to save database in memory.
is there a way to execute a query in this system?
for example:

```
Select name from Employee where sal>20000
```

thank you

Comment: please i need an answer

Comment: JCS is a cache not a database. You cannot execute a query on it. Check the 'What JCS is not' section of the following link http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/.